# what are the changes that have to be made after implementing ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html

**The Idea:**

I'm using the CKEditor to post questions in the forum of my website.

**The Problem:**

When I enter the question in the post_body textarea and hit create topic, the following is happening:-

- Firstly, an alert box pops up saying "please type something into the
  body"(please not that the body textarea is not null)
- And then Immediately, I'm redirected to the topic.(please note that the posted content in the body is getting inserted into the database table)

I don't want that alert box to pop up. What should I do?

**Code:**

```
<div id="middlePanel">
    <table style="background-color:#FFF; border:#069 1px solid; border-top:none;" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="12" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="80%" valign="top">
          <h2><?php echo $forum_section_title; ?></h2>
          <div id="breadcrumbs"><a href="forumhome.php">Forum</a>&larr;<a href="sections.php?id=<?php echo $forum_section_id; ?>"><?php echo $forum_section_title; ?></a></div><br /><br />
          <h2>Creating New Topic In the  <em><?php echo $forum_section_title; ?></em>&nbsp; Forum</h2>
          <form action="php_parsers/forumpost_system.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
            <input name="post_type" type="hidden" value="a" />
            Topic Author:<br /><input name="topic_author" type="text" disabled="disabled" maxlength="64" style="width:96%;" value="<?php echo $log_username; ?>" />
            <br /><br />
            Please type in a title for your topic here:<br /><input name="post_title" type="text" maxlength="64" style="width:96%;" /><br /><br />
            Please type in your topic body:<br />
            <textarea name="post_body" id="post_body" rows="15" style="width:96%;"></textarea>
            <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'post_body' );
            </script>
            <!--<iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" style="border:#000000 1px solid; width:700px; height:300px;"></iframe>-->
            <br /><br />
            <input name="" type="submit" value="Create my topic now!" onclick="validateMyForm();"/>
            <input name="fsid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $forum_section_id; ?>"/>
            <input name="fstitle" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $forum_section_title; ?>"/>
            <input name="uid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $log_id; ?>"/>
            <input name="uname" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $log_username; ?>"/>
            <input name="upass" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $log_password; ?>"/>
          </form>
        </td>
        <td width="20%" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

These are the javascript functions in my head tag

```
<script> 
function validateMyForm ( ) 
{ 
    var isValid = true;
    if ( document.form1.post_title.value == "" ) 
    { 
        alert ( "Please type in a title for this topic" ); 
        isValid = false;
    } 
    else if ( document.form1.post_title.value.length < 10 ) 
    { 
        alert ( "Your title must be at least 10 characters long" ); 
        isValid = false;
    } 
    else if ( document.form1.post_body.value == "" ) 
    { 
        alert ( "Please type in your topic body." ); 
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

If i'm not using CKEditor, then everything works fine. But if i'm using it, i'm facing the above problem. I think that i have to make some changes that i'm not aware of. So people who are using CKEditors out there, please help me.

Comment: I presume the alert is coming from some javascript that you've decided (for some reason) not to show us?

Comment: I have updated the qn. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not telling CKEditor to update the original `<textarea>` element.

When you use CKEditor, the editor will use the content of the `<textarea>` to populate itself - and when you submit the form, the editor will automatically update that `<textarea>` with the edited contents of the editor.

What you need to do is force it to do update the element early, before you check the contents of that element.

So, before you test `document.form1.post_body.value` try running the following bit of code...

```
CKEDITOR.instances.post_body.updateElement();
```